# Backing oak with fir in cabinetry

Tags: moisture, panel, oak

I saw some fancy oak paneling which included 14-foot quarter sawn boards and was told that under the paneling was base of fir boards and this was important to stabilize oak and without it the oak would distort. Does anyone have any opinion or further information about this?

Comment: That's nonsense, oak (especially QS) can be very stable. In far wider boards than are available commercially now it used to be used to panel entire houses, all rooms (including bathrooms), hallways, staircases. And of course this is in the days prior to any kind of climate control. I wonder if they're just maximising the amount of material of a given thickness they can get from a nice log, so this stabilising thing is a pseudo-reason. If that's the case I don't see any reason they have to excuse doing so since veneer is hardly non-standard.

Comment: @Graphus maybe the idea was to have the oak thick enough that they could get away with _not_ calling it veneer, but yet thin enough to maximize the surface area they could cover. The fir backing would then be the actual structure while the oak was the pretty.

Comment: @FreeMan, yes that could well be the case.... although I'm sure we'll never know just how thick the oak surface would be even if we ask!